# Get yaml key value in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

My yaml file is:

```
clusters:
    test:                           
      tag_cl: tag0
    mtest:                           
      tag_cl: tag1, tag12
    ctest3:                           
      tag_cl: tag2, tag22
```

I want to get value of each `tag_cl`. I am expecting a below output:

```
tag0
tag1, tag12
tag2, tage22
```

I tried doing:

```
stream = open('clusters.yml', 'r')
data = yaml.load(stream)
var = data.get('clusters').get('test').get('tag_cl')
```

and just wondering if there is a way to have `*` instead of `get('test')` so that I can fetch it for all.

Please help

Comment: Show us what you already tried, and what is not working. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`data` is a python dictionary. You can retrieve all the data by iterating through `data` as a dictionary. Note that you can also access python dictionaries by using `["clusters"]` instead of `.get("clusters")`.

You would do something like:

```
for k, v in data["clusters"].items():
    print data["clusters"][k]["tag_cl"]
```

**EDIT**

If you want to check if there is a `"tag_cl"` key in the `data`, you can use the `.has_key()` method:

```
for k, v in data["clusters"].items():
    if data["clusters"][k].has_key("tag_cl"):
        print data["clusters"][k]["tag_cl"]
```

Comment: great, it works well. What if some items in [k] does not have `tag_cl` ??

Comment: @SJJ you could just add an `if` statement to check if there is, ill update my post.

Comment: Great! Works like charm. Thank you! :)

Comment: How can I print "test:", "mtest:", "ctest3:" ?

Comment: @SJJ Please read the python documentation on [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=data%20structures#dictionaries). You would use `.keys()`

Answer (score 7):

You can use a recursive generator like so:

```
import yaml

def find(d, tag):
    if tag in d:
        yield d[tag]
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            for i in find(v, tag):
                yield i

stream = open('clusters.yml', 'r')
data = yaml.load(stream)

for val in find(data, 'tag_cl'):
    print val
```

This will return the values associated with all keys matching the specified tag, regardless of nesting depth (within reason).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found out:

```
In[17]: d
Out[17]: 
{'clusters': {'ctest3': {'tag_cl': 'tag2, tag22'},
  'mtest': {'tag_cl': 'tag1, tag12'},
  'test': {'tag_cl': 'tag0'}}}

In[18]: d['clusters']
Out[18]: 
{'ctest3': {'tag_cl': 'tag2, tag22'},
 'mtest': {'tag_cl': 'tag1, tag12'},
 'test': {'tag_cl': 'tag0'}}

In[19]: for it in d['clusters'].items():
    print('{} ==> {}'.format(*it))

ctest3 ==> {'tag_cl': 'tag2, tag22'}
test ==> {'tag_cl': 'tag0'}
mtest ==> {'tag_cl': 'tag1, tag12'}

In[20]: [v for v in d['clusters'].values()]
Out[20]: [{'tag_cl': 'tag2, tag22'}, {'tag_cl': 'tag0'}, {'tag_cl': 'tag1, tag12'}]

In[21]: [v['tag_cl'] for v in d['clusters'].values()]
Out[21]: ['tag2, tag22', 'tag0', 'tag1, tag12']
```

## Notes

- Line 17: Our dictionary is `d`
- Line 18: Most of the good stuff is in `d['clusters']`
- Line 19: Exploring: the stuff we want is in `d['clusters'].items()`
- Line 20: Specifically, they are in `d['clusters'].values()`. Getting close.
- Line 21: Bingo.

Comment: I need to script it