# How do I access a variable inside a YAML file from an AWS Lambda function?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm using the Serverless framework to test my lamdba function, but it requires that I access my yaml file to get a specific variable. I'll add the file and the code below for clarity:

The YAML variable that I need to access is tableName

```
environment:
  tableName: notes_project
```

Here's the lambda function:

```
import json
import boto3
import uuid

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

table = dynamodb.Table('notes_project')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    data = json.loads(event['body'])

    item = {
        'user_id': event['requestContext']['identity']['cognitoIdentityId'],
        'note_id': str(uuid.uuid1()),
        'note_text': data
    }

    table.put_item( Item = item)
```

At the moment, you can see that the table name is hardcoded, but I want to avoid that.

What I've tried so far:

I've looked at [Get yaml key value in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37626662/get-yaml-key-value-in-python) and other suggestions involving os.environ but I'm unsure if these are the right options if I'm going to be deploying the code to AWS. I am mostly ignorant as to how the lambda code would access these yaml variables once they've been deployed. An explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `serverless.yml` will not be uploaded to the lambda function code, therefore you would not have access to that file.

you can do this in few ways,

#### Store the value as environment variable directly in serverless.yml

Define environment variables for lambda in `serverless.yml`. then you can access the environment variables in lambda.

```
#serverless.yml
service: my-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    environment:
      # store the value directly
      deliveryMethod: email
```

#### store the parameter in SSM store

Store the parameters in SSM parameter store and reference it in `serverless.yml`

```
#serverless.yml
service: my-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    environment:
      # store the value directly
      deliveryMethod: ${ssm:/path/to/deliveryMethod}
```

Then in the lambda code:

```
# lambda code
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    deliveryMethod = os.environ['deliveryMethod']
```

Hope this helps.

Reference:
https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/

Comment: Thanks for the answer Arun! To clarify, is this specific to Python? The example I'm looking at uses NodeJS and the way they're doing it is as follows (the comments are from the example):
  const params = {
    **TableName: process.env.tableName,**
  };

The YAML File:
**environment: tableName: notes**

Aparently the variables from the YAML file are made available through "**process.env.**"

Comment: The lambda code is python. I thought what you wanted was python since your question has python code. If you want to use nodejs, you are right, it will be `process.env.tableName`

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I wasn't clear enough. I am trying to redo the tutorial in Python myself. But I'm wondering how to achieve the same effect

Comment: How do I reference that environment variable directly? So in YAML would it be environment: tableName: 'notes_project' and then in the lambda function I would use os.environ['tableName']?

Comment: yes in lambda it will be `os.environ['tableName']` for python or `process.env.tableName` for nodejs

Comment: appreciate the feedback, glad to be of help